# How I can make a checkbox filter?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, filter, filtering

I need to find a solution for my script, because I gives me duplicated results.

There is something that I made:

https://jsfiddle.net/4m3twsjd/1/

```
        function myFunction() {
        if(a % 2 == 0){
          document.getElementById('h1').innerHTML += M
        }

        else {
          document.getElementById('h1').innerHTML = document.getElementById('h1').innerHTML.replace(M, '')
        }
        a++
}
```

How to make it to not show the same element when clicked two or three checkboxes ?

Thanks you in advance all for this. I need some simply code, because I'm not a coder.

I need to have something that there are 4 brand and 5 power ranges. And If I click on checkbox with 1 brand it shows me all devices that belong to this brand. Also If I checked 1 power range it shows me all devices with that power range. And I works like this right now.

The problem is that if I checked 1 brand and 1 power range it shows me all deviced that belong to this brand and all devices with that power - so the devices are sometimes duplicated. How to fix it?

Also how can I make it posible to show each device with name, photo, description and link (when some checkbox checked)?

Comment: Can you describe what is your final goal with this script?

Comment: Could you try reframing your question better as it is still not clear what you need help with, it is hard to relate the code to the problem. Try saying what you're trying to do and what **exactly** the error is or what you need help with.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your question/ end-goal is not clear to me. Here is a link to help with the fundamentals of how to do ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

About your code, there are many `basic` issues with the way you have tried to achieve your objective. Do a little research on global vs local variables, checkbox states to begin with.

Comment: Is this know understanded?

Comment: Can somebody help?